# A small inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Given two real number $\alpha , \beta $ such that $0\le \alpha <\beta \le 1$ and $n$ non-zero real numbers $a_1, \dots , a_n$, then there always exists a number $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha <{a_it}<\beta $ for $i=1, \dots , n$.

I thought that the case when $\alpha=0$ immediately solves the problem by choosing $t\in (0,\frac{\beta}{max\{a_i\}})$, but cant move to the general case

Comment: this statement is false: for one thing, if some of the $a_i$ are negative and others are positive, no matter what $t$ is, the numbers $a_it$ will also contain positive and negative among them and can't all be between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Oh so the statement can be true for non-negative $a_i$'s right?

Comment: not always. If for example $n=2$ and $a_1=1,a_2=1000$ while $\alpha=0.99,\beta=1$ then it's clear there's no such $t$ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that the $a_i$ all have the same sign, your idea works and generalizes to

$$\frac{\alpha}{\min a_i}<t<\frac{\beta}{\max{a_i}}$$

Sometimes there isn't any values of $t$ that satisfy this inequality. In those cases the problem is impossible.

Comment: @ downvoter, why did you not like this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just take
$$
t\in\left]\frac{\alpha}{\min a_i},\frac{\beta}{\max a_i}\right[\;\;.
$$

Comment: I really really hate the notation $]a,b[$ aesthetically

Comment: Let me just add that I really, *really*  hate it. A lot.

Comment: enough to downvote...?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry no, just enough the fume in the comments :) This answer has not been downvoted, and you can see that by clicking the score.